# How to get product Review/Ratings notification via email in Magento2

Tags: magento2, email, adminnotification

In Magento2, Whenever a new product review posted in my store, I couldn’t get any notification. I’m always navigating to the review section to check and moderate the reviews/ratings. Is there any admin configuration available to get the product reviews/ratings notification via email?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found such option by default in CE.

You could create a simple module that does it. Create standard module structure/files, then:

etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="review_save_after"> 
    <observer name="Foo_ReviewNotification::review_save_after" instance="Foo\ReviewNotification\Observer\ReviewObserver" />
</event>
```

observer/ReviewObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Foo\ReviewNotification\Observer;

class ReviewObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_registry;
  protected $_scopeConfig;

  public function __construct(     
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
  ) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {        
    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    $notifyEmail = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("trans_email/ident_general/email", $storeScope);

    $product = $this->_registry->registry("current_product");
    $name = $product->getName();
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $emailBody = "Product name: {$name} \n SKU: {$sku} \n Review id: {$review->getId()} \n Customer id: {$review->getCustomerId()}";
    // Mail me
    $headers = "From: {$notifyEmail}\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: {$notifyEmail}\r\n";
    mail($notifyEmail,"New product review - {$name}", $emailBody, $headers);
    return;
  }
}
```

That's a very basic module. You can improve it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing.

> app/code/vendor/module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="review_save_after"> 
    <observer name="vendor_email_review" instance="vendor\module\Observer\ReviewObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

> app/code/vendor/module/Observer/ReviewObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class ReviewObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_registry;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    private $_productRepository;
    protected $_reviewFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, TransportBuilder $transportBuilder, \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository, \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        if ($state->getAreaCode() != 'adminhtml')
        {
            $revieww = $observer->getEvent()
                ->getDataObject();
            $reviewId = $revieww->getReviewId();
            $product = $this
                ->_registry
                ->registry("current_product");
            $name = $product->getName();
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $productt = $this
                ->_productRepository
                ->getById($product->getId());
            $prodlink = $productt->getUrlModel()
                ->getUrl($productt);
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $rtitile = $this
                ->_reviewFactory
                ->create()
                ->load($reviewId)->getTitle();
            $rdetail = $this
                ->_reviewFactory
                ->create()
                ->load($reviewId)->getDetail();
            $rdate = $this
                ->_reviewFactory
                ->create()
                ->load($reviewId)->getCreatedAt();
            $storeEmail = $this
                ->_scopeConfig
                ->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/email', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
            $storeName = $this
                ->_scopeConfig
                ->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/name', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
            $receiverInfo = ['name' => $storeName, 'email' => $storeEmail];
            $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
            if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn())
            {
                $email = $customerSession->getCustomer()
                    ->getEmail();
                $uname = $customerSession->getCustomer()
                    ->getName();
            }
            else
            {
                $email = "Guest";
                $uname = "Guest";
            }
            $store = $this
                ->_storeManager
                ->getStore();
            $templateParams = array();
            $templateParams['review_id'] = $reviewId;
            $templateParams['product_name'] = $name;
            $templateParams['email'] = $email;
            $templateParams['store'] = $store;
            $templateParams['prodlink'] = $prodlink;
            $templateParams['uname'] = $uname;
            $templateParams['administrator_name'] = $receiverInfo['name'];
            $templateParams['sku'] = $sku;
            $templateParams['rtitle'] = $rtitile;
            $templateParams['rdetail'] = $rdetail;
            $templateParams['rdate'] = $rdate;
            $transport = $this
                ->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('review_email_observer')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store->getId() ])
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'], $receiverInfo['name'])->setTemplateVars($templateParams)->setFrom('general')
                ->getTransport();
            try
            {
                $transport->sendMessage();
            }
            catch(\Exception $e)
            {
                $this
                    ->logger
                    ->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/vendor/module/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
  <template id="review_email_observer" label="ReviewObserver" file="reviewemail.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/email/reviewemail.html

<!--@subject {{trans "New Review from %uname has been submitted on %product_name" product_name=$product_name  uname=$uname}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
"var customer.name":"Customer Name",
"var administrator_name":"Administrator Name"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<p class="greeting">{{trans "Hello <b>%administrator_name</b>," administrator_name=$administrator_name|row}}</p>

<p>{{trans 'The customer named <b>%uname</b> just submitted a review on  %store_name:' uname=$uname store_name=$store.getBaseUrl()|row}}</p>
<table style="width: 750px;border-collapse: collapse;margin:50px auto;" border="1px">
  <tr style="background: #eee;">
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Review ID</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'>%review_id</td>" review_id=$review_id|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>SKU</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'>%sku</td>" sku=$sku|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr style="background: #eee;">
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Product</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><a href='%prodlink'>%product_name</a></td>" product_name=$product_name prodlink=$prodlink|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Review Summary</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'>%rtitle</td>" rtitle=$rtitle|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr style="background: #eee;">
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Review Detail</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><q><i>%rdetail</i></q></td>" rdetail=$rdetail|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Customer Name<b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'>%uname</td>" uname=$uname|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr style="background: #eee;">
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Customer Email</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'>%email</td>" email=$email|row}}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'><b>Date & Time</b></td>
    {{trans "<td style='padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;font-size: 18px;'>%rdate</td>" rdate=$rdate|row}}
  </tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```